# zombie not showing up in instrumentation on xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, nszombie

Enabled NSZombieEnable
Run App in ios 7 sim
Went to a specific operation that crashes
Boom  -[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe1852f80

I fire up instrument
Choose Zombie from the memory options
do the same thing in app
and nothing happens, no zombie messaged popups :(

Any ideas? xcode bug?
Thanks

Comment: Check mark the `log exceptions` as well, where you have checked for zombie under `Edit scheme`.

Comment: I enabled the log exceptions, but still the zombie tool didn't detect anything.One possible clue, this error wasn't showing up, the it started popping up now and then and now its ALWAYS coming up. I tried the project on another machine and no issues came up. Any ideas? Also what should I do with log exceptions?

Comment: ok can you share us your observation you have right now? I mean what is the message popped up ?

Comment: No message popped up in instruments, it passed by as if nothing. In consol I saw "message sent to deallocated" and before that I saw a "exc bad access" as a breakpoint in the machine code. BUT... I found my bug, I was calling CGImageRelease on the wrong image. What is crazy is that it didn't pop up as a bug until now. Ive executed that code int he project for a very long time. AND it works on my laptop, only explodes on the mac mini. Still couldn't get zombie to catch it. I basically put return statments in my code to see how I can exit and not get this error.

Comment: Glad to see you solved it! :) Happy coding...